# How can I exclude all “permission denied” result lines from “grep”?

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, grep

So, the thing is, I'm on linux terminal using grep command and I want the output without all the lines where it prints at the beginning "grep:" or the lines that begins with "./", because now I'm getting something like this:

```
grep: ./users/blabla1: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla2: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla3: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla4: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla5: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla6: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla7: Permission denied
grep: ./users/blabla8: Permission denied
./foo/bar/log.log
./foo/bar/xml.xml
```

I have tried this:

```
grep -irl "foo" . | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

I have also tried this one:

```
 grep -irl "foo" . | grep -v "^grep:"
```

And finally this one:

```
 grep -irl "foo" . | grep "^./"
```

But I keep getting same results as if I haven't put anything after the |, any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 71):

I prefer to use the -s 'suppress' flag:

```
grep -irls "foo"
```

Note the "Portability note" from the grep man page:

> -s, --no-messages
>
> Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files. Portability note: unlike  GNU  grep, 7th Edition Unix grep did not conform to POSIX, because it lacked -q and its -s option behaved like GNU grep's -q option. USG-style grep also lacked -q but its -s option behaved like GNU grep. Portable shell scripts should avoid both -q and -s and should redirect standard and error output to /dev/null instead. (-s is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: I think this is a better answer for the requirement. You can search -s flag in official documentation [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: A tip for remembering this is that you are looking for "girls" called "foo": grep -irls "foo"

Answer (score 65):

The messages you are receiving is due to a lack of permission on those files, i.e., those are error messages.

All you have to do is to redirect the `stderr` (standard error output) to `/dev/null`, like this:

```
grep -irl "foo" 2> /dev/null
```

To lear more about redirection (on bash), read this article:
[Bash Reference Manual - Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)

**Edit**: You can also just suppress error messages by using:

```
grep -irl "foo" 2>&-
```

Comment: I haven't explained myself clearly, thank you very much by the way.
I know that I don't have permission, and I can't get it. The thing is, I don't know the results of the grep, not all of them are in `./foo`, they could be anywhere, I can get `./foo` or `./bar`, I just want to discard all the results that shows I don't have permission.

Comment: @gleba, this is what the redirection is supposed to do. All the results (`stdout`) will be displayed except for the `Permission denied` entries (`stderr`).
You  can re-test your command just adding `2> /dev/null` at the end

Comment: And thus with this perfectly clear answer I finally understood what `2>` means in terminal (it's hard to search)

Comment: Not a good solution because it will exclude all errors, not just the permission errors. OP is wants to hide permission errors, but there may be other errors he wants to see.

Answer (score 2):

Going off of your first try:

```
grep -irl "foo" . | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

You're just missing the operator to redirect standard error. '|' redirects standard output. if you add '&', you will also redirect standard error, which is what is giving you the "Permission denied" message. Try:

```
grep -irl "foo" . &| grep -v "Permission denied"
```

This works for me, because for some reason my machine doesn't like the "2> /dev/null" option.